# Установить term id для поста

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

мне нужно установить на просроченные ивенты категорию "просрочено".
для постов с post_type=mec-events нужно поставить taxonomy=mec_category и term_id=40
помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо использовать ф-цию wp_set_post_terms.

```
wp_set_post_terms( $post_ID, $term_id, 'mec_category' );
```

Подробнее: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_set_post_terms